# Save FileStorage OpenCV + Python

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, surf, file-storage, opencv3.1

I am trying to extract keypoints from an image. The image is a frame from a video I captured myself.

[image]
I already extracted the keypoints using **SURF**.

[image: SURF]

I found `cv2.FileStorage` and `cv2.FileNode`in the help but I don't know how to use them.

```
FileNode(...)
        FileNode() -> <FileNode object>

    FileStorage(...)
        FileStorage([source, flags[, encoding]]) -> <FileStorage object>
```

Every time I try to dump the keypoints to a file using `cPickle`, `json` or `numpy`

> I get an error from these libraries for not being able to save a cv2.FileStorage file type.

I found the [official documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/xml_yaml_persistence.html) of opencv for C++ on how to save these type of files, but I haven't found one for Python yet.

What I want to do is to dump these keypoints into an **XML** file for later use for object detection and recognition.

Comment: Btw, SURF are more useful if computed on a grayscale image ;D

Comment: @Miki I need to extract the keypoints for BOVW so I don't need the extra keypoints observed in the background. That's why I am applying it on B&W image.